# How to write the contract using ERC1178 standard

Tags: solidity

I have read the erc1178 standard and write the multi-token contract.
but tokens don't shown on Metamask.
please help me.

Comment: What does the contract look like? EIP-1178 has been deprecated in favor of EIP-1155. It appears that EIP-1155 isn't supported by Metamask yet, https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/5887.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
I used the erc-1178 sample. see the [Link](https://github.com/albertchon/ERC-1178/blob/master/erc1178-sample.sol).
Multiple tokens should be implemented for fungible tokens and not non-fungible tokens.
If you understand, please let me know how to solve it.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't heard much about ERC-1178. If you want something more standard use EIP-1155 that should provide both type of tokens in a single contract, OpenZeppelin has implemented that EIP.